# how to queue sqlite db transactions in qt?

Tags: qt, sqlite

In my project, we have various threads that uses a singleton object -  cachequery to write/read into the database. I see that that if two threads try to write on to the database, one of the thread fails to write on the db - throws sqlite - db transaction error.My aim here is to queue the transactions that fails to write on to the db. What is the best way to do so? Is there any way to queue those transactions? Or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: you should come up with a worker thread doing queries for you there are not plenty recourses on the web for a solution in qt , some are (http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9602) , (http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/coe518/LinuxJournal/elj2007-158-asynQt.pdf)

Comment: I liked the journal. can you please share some more examples on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the database related operations in `cachequery` in relevant slots. Different threads can interact with the `cachequery` object through connecting their signals to it's slots. Since the emitter and receiver exist in different threads, you will have a queued connection type. So different signals that are emitted from different threads would be queued in `cachequery` to be processed.